# Работа с ASCII в C

Tags: c, ascii

У меня есть два текста, в которых нужно найти одинаковые слова.
Как сделать так, чтоб буква `А` считывалась программой как `а` - то есть чтобы для программы был неважен регистр символа.
Программа на C.

Comment: после считывания можно просто приводить все к нижнему/верхнему регистру, например с помощью [tolower](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/tolower/)

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете либо использовать такую конструкцию:

```
if (c == 'A' || с == 'a')
```

или как подсказано в комментариях привести весь входящий поток к тому регистру который вам удобен стандартными функциями **(toupper)** или **(tolower)**

```
char *ft_tolower(char *s)
{
    char *ptr;

    ptr = s;
    if(s)
    while (*ptr != '\0')
    {
        if (*ptr >= 65 && *ptr <= 90)
            *ptr += 32
        ptr++;
    }
    return (s);
}
```

Где **s** это ваш массив строк, который нужно привести к нижнему регистру.

Comment: Э... Зачем велосипедить, если есть `ctype.h`?